# How to fix 'strpos(): Offset not contained in string' on this code

Tags: php

Some of my code is throwing error some times, and can't find why.
The error is `strpos(): Offset not contained in string` on the `while` statement.

I know what this error means, but I don't know why sometimes I have this error...

Here is the part of code:

```
if(!empty($args['name'])){
  $p = 0;
  while(($p = strpos($args['name'],'&',$p)) !== false){
    if(substr($args['name'],$p,5) == '&amp;'){
      $p += 5;
    }else{
      ++$p;
      $args['name'] = substr($args['name'],0,$p).'amp;'.substr($args['name'],$p);
      $p += 4;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to change the While statement by:

```
while(strlen($args['name']) >= $p &&  ($p = strpos($args['name'],'&',$p)) !== false){
```

But it doesn't fix the issue.

By the way, this code comes from a wordpress plugin, here is the doc:

```
/** A workaround for seems to be an overlook in WordPress core.
* Dealing with '&' in term name.
* A term name containing '&' is stored in database with '&amp;' instead of '&',
* but search in get_terms is done on raw '&' coming from $_POST variable.
*/
```

Do you have any ideas? Why this code is sometimes wrong?

Thank you

**FIXED**
My variable was an `Array` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work fine. Is ok.

In your case `$p` can't be greater than your paramater.

Please just be sure that your parameter `$args['name']` is a `string`. I'm pretty sure it's not.
I'd bet it's an array (`is_array()`)

Comment: Oh my god! I'm so sorry everyone! It was Array! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `$args['name']` before your while loop

Add  `if(isset($args['name']))` or more sure with `if(!empty($args['name']))`

Comment: My bad, I forgot, but I already have the `if(!empty($args['name'])){`

Comment: @user3013440 to try with `stripos` replace for `strpos`